# Who played Luke in the Forceback?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, luke-skywalker

In *The Force Awakens*, Rey has a "Forceback" of sorts after touching the Skywalker lightsaber. One of the scenes she witnesses is Luke's metallic hand reaching out to touch R2-D2. What I'm wondering is the actor behind the hand. Was it Mark Hamill or a stand-in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to *The Force Awakens* actor Simon Pegg, Mark Hamill played the part.](https://www.outerplaces.com/science-fiction/item/10526-simon-pegg-reveals-the-owner-of-the-robotic-hand-from-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-trailer)

> I am on set as a consultant, acting as a sounding board for J.J., who is making tweaks to the already wonderful screenplay. My computer is open in Final Draft and, at the top of my screen, the scene heading reads, "INT. S-REDACTED-R – Day". I hear a familiar voice and turn to see Mark walking onto set, looking trim and cool, with a beard that he grumbles about but makes him look handsome and Jedi-like. When they shot Luke placing his robotic hand on R2's head, a moment glimpsed in the trailer, I sat at the monitors with Mark's family and marvelled at the huge significance of the moment.